# How to bring two words separated by a dash into one with tidyverse, R based on a condition

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I am trying to get one column with different structure of the strings either merged together or separated. I wish this will be done with tidyverse, in R.

this is a very simple nibble with only 5 rows.

```
t <- tibble(med_name = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin"))
```

However, my original dataset has 700 different rows with different cases.
Therefore, I am in need of a code that applies to different structure of the strings.

this is the desired output

```
desired_output <- tibble(med_name = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin"), 
             desired_output_1 = c("Coamoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin","Cotrimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride"), 
             desired_output_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  "Vancomycin"))
```

As you can see `Co-amoxiclac` is brought together into one word - `Coamoxiclav`, same applied to `Co-trimozaxole`. Yet, `Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin` is brought into two different strings - `Sodium Chloride` and `Vancomycin` both brought into different columns.

However, I have tried the function `separate` and it does not do the job.

Can someone please help me with this?

====================Updated from this line bellow ===========

Akrun - the code bellow - a really elegant one - gets me this

```
structure(list(med_name = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", 
"Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin", 
"Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), new1 = c("Co-amoxiclav", 
"doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride", 
"Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), new2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Vancomycin", "Tazobactam (contains penicillin)")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But another pattern you've asked for is medicine followed by + followed by another medicine . So another pattern I missed to mention above is as it is in this sample data:

```
dt <- tibble(med_name = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin", 
                          "Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"))
```

With desired output similar to the above but updated to another pattern.

```
desired_output <- tibble(med_name = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin","Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), 
             desired_output_1 = c("Coamoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin","Cotrimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride", "Piperacillin"), 
             desired_output_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  "Vancomycin", "Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"))
```

Comment: How would it possibly know what to do for `Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin`? Do you have a reference list of sorts? Removing a `-` is easy enough, but understanding which words to pick would require some sort of chemical lexicon or whatnot.

Comment: Adam, you are right. I have the list. I thought that will be another problem and then requested to post it as another issue. But let me attach the list

Comment: @Adam is there a way to get rid of the dash in between the words? Thank you

Comment: Check out `str_remove_all()` from `stringr`. That will probably be the easiest if you do not have a lot of experience with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the pattern showed, an option is to use `trimws` to remove substring from 'med_name' with a regex in `whitespace` i.e. specify zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by a digit (`[0-9]`) and other characters (`.*`), this will get the first blocks of chemical names, then in the second column, we need to get the substring after the `+`.  Here, we detect whereever there are `+` with a conditional expression in `case_when` and return only those elements after the `+` while the others will be `NA` by default

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
t %>%
  mutate(new1 = trimws(med_name, whitespace = '\\s*[0-9].*'), 
         new2 = case_when(str_detect(med_name, "\\+") ~ 
          trimws(med_name, whitespace = '.*\\+\\s+')))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  med_name                                                new1            new2      
#  <chr>                                                   <chr>           <chr>     
#1 Co-amoxiclav                                            Co-amoxiclav    <NA>      
#2 doxycycline                                             doxycycline     <NA>      
#3 Gentamicin                                              Gentamicin      <NA>      
#4 Co-trimoxazole                                          Co-trimoxazole  <NA>      
#5 Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin Sodium Chloride Vancomycin
```

---

For the second case, we could just an `|` condition

```
dt %>%
 mutate(new1 = trimws(med_name, whitespace = '\\s*[0-9].*|\\s*\\+.*'), 
     new2 = case_when(str_detect(med_name, "\\+") ~ 
      trimws(med_name, whitespace = '.*\\+\\s+')))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  med_name                                                new1            new2                            
#  <chr>                                                   <chr>           <chr>                           
#1 Co-amoxiclav                                            Co-amoxiclav    <NA>                            
#2 doxycycline                                             doxycycline     <NA>                            
#3 Gentamicin                                              Gentamicin      <NA>                            
#4 Co-trimoxazole                                          Co-trimoxazole  <NA>                            
#5 Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin Sodium Chloride Vancomycin                      
#6 Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)         Piperacillin    Tazobactam (contains penicillin)
```

Comment: wow! akrun - this worked like magic. Nevertheless, can you please help me, were to go a full picture in how to deal with these types of problems? I mean is there a specific resource you get?

Comment: @GaB regex will be based on the patterns.  So, in the example showed, it matches those cases to extract only those words (i added some description in the post).  You can check out regex tutorials  like [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: one aspect, the second column comes with two chemicals separated by + . Is there a way, in the second column to get only first word and then in the third the third word?

Comment: @GaB do you have another pattern

Comment: yes, updated in the original post outlining the pattern I have missed. Sorry about it

Comment: @GaB Sorry, was away with some work related troubleshooting.  Can you check the updated code